# Basic Swing GUI with JDBC connection filling labels with info from query

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

Currently, I have created a Swing GUI to pull data from a basic database.

Eventually, I want to build this into a point of sale system and this is the start.

Once I get the "basics" down I will be able to expand it with different tabs and more items.

For now the query is able to pull the data and I can get the code to print to the console, but when I try to implement it to each label, or text box it will only display on one text box, and not others.

Is a loop needed to cycle through each of my labels, as they are labeled label1, label2...? Then how do I ensure the SQL query loads to each label? In the loop do I sort of the productID?

I tried using multiple queries and get a result set is closed error, and figured there is an easier way to get the data.

Here is the code:

```java
package application;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;

public class Application extends JFrame {

    private JTextField prc2;
    private JTextField prc1;
    //private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Application frame = new Application();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Application() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        getContentPane().add(desktopPane);

        prc2 = new JTextField();
        prc2.setBounds(70, 111, 86, 20);
        desktopPane.add(prc2);
        prc2.setColumns(10);

        prc1 = new JTextField();
        prc1.setBounds(70, 80, 86, 20);
        desktopPane.add(prc1);
        prc1.setColumns(10);

        JLabel item1 = new JLabel("New label");
        item1.setBounds(10, 83, 46, 14);
        desktopPane.add(item1);

        JLabel item2 = new JLabel("New label");
        item2.setBounds(10, 114, 46, 14);
        desktopPane.add(item2);

        JLabel qty1 = new JLabel("New label");
        qty1.setBounds(181, 83, 46, 14);
        desktopPane.add(qty1);

        JLabel qty2 = new JLabel("New label");
        qty2.setBounds(181, 114, 46, 14);
        desktopPane.add(qty2);

        JLabel qty = new JLabel("Quantity");
        qty.setBounds(181, 40, 46, 14);
        desktopPane.add(qty);

        JLabel Price = new JLabel("PRICE");
        Price.setBounds(70, 40, 46, 14);
        desktopPane.add(Price);

        Connection conn = null;
        //Statement stmt = null;
        //ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        try {
            String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName = Capstone; username=dbuser; password=password";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM dbo.products WHERE ProductID = 1";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("ProductID");
                String productName = rs.getString("productName");
                String quant = rs.getString("productQty");
                String price = rs.getString("ProductPrice");

                item1.setText(productName);
                qty1.setText(quant);
                prc1.setText(price);
            }
            String sqlStmt1 = "SELECT * FROM dbo.products WHERE ProductID = 2";
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt1);
            while (rs1.next()) {
                int id1 = rs.getInt("ProductID");
                String productName1 = rs.getString("productName");
                String quant1 = rs.getString("productQty");
                String price1 = rs.getString("ProductPrice");

                item2.setText(productName1);
                qty2.setText(quant1);
                prc2.setText(price1);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

If I missed a question that is similar please point me in the right direction.

Comment: *"Is a loop needed to cycle through each of my labels,"* Use a `JTable` for tabular data. The default table models often accept a `List` structure in the constructor. **General Tip:** Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Don't mix JavaFX classes in a Swing application.

Comment: This is really basically a JDBD/SQL question